# How to authenticate users stored in a file with JWT authentication of DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a list of users in a file, I want JWT authentication of Django Rest Framework to authenticate these users (I do not want to insert these users into database). How can do it, or could you please help to provide some reference?

Comment: Cloud you please explain a little more of your use case. Your problem description looks very vague.

Comment: @JeetPatel I have a list file of account, i want to make jwt authentication with these account in DRF (use these account to pass authentication and authorization). Normally we will store user in database, but in my case, the users was stored in a file.